# State passed through props undefined in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote this code for a todo list. It generates li elements but doesn't load the text stored in `state.text`.

```js
class TodoWholistic extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tasks: [], text: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            id="new-task"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.text}
            placeholder="Type some text here..."
          />
          <button>+</button>
        </form>
        <TodoList tasks={this.state.tasks} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    const newTask = {
      tasks: this.state.text,
      id: Date.now(),
    };
    this.setState((state) => ({
      tasks: state.tasks.concat(newTask),
      text: "",
    }));
  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
          <li key={task.id}>{task.text}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoWholistic />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are iterating over the `state.tasks`, which includes two property *(`tasks` and `id`)* and you are storing the `state.text` value in the `tasks` property which is kinda messy and I don't know your intention about it. But to solve your current problem you can either refer to the `tasks` property or change the `tasks` object key to `text`, where both of them are fine.

1. **Refer to `tasks`:**

   ```js
   class TodoWholistic extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { tasks: [], text: "" };
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <input
               id="new-task"
               onChange={this.handleChange}
               value={this.state.text}
               placeholder="Type some text here..."
             />
             <button>+</button>
           </form>
           <TodoList tasks={this.state.tasks} />
         </div>
       );
     }

     handleChange(e) {
       this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
     }

     handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
         return;
       }

       const newTask = {
         tasks: this.state.text,
         id: Date.now(),
       };
       this.setState((state) => ({
         tasks: state.tasks.concat(newTask),
         text: "",
       }));
     }
   }

   class TodoList extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <ul>
           {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
             <li key={task.id}>{task.tasks}</li>
           ))}
         </ul>
       );
     }
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<TodoWholistic />, document.getElementById("root"));
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```
2. **Change `tasks` to `text`:**

   ```js
   class TodoWholistic extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { tasks: [], text: "" };
       this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
       this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <div>
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
             <input
               id="new-task"
               onChange={this.handleChange}
               value={this.state.text}
               placeholder="Type some text here..."
             />
             <button>+</button>
           </form>
           <TodoList tasks={this.state.tasks} />
         </div>
       );
     }

     handleChange(e) {
       this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
     }

     handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if (this.state.text.length === 0) {
         return;
       }

       const newTask = {
         text: this.state.text,
         id: Date.now(),
       };
       this.setState((state) => ({
         tasks: state.tasks.concat(newTask),
         text: "",
       }));
     }
   }

   class TodoList extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <ul>
           {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
             <li key={task.id}>{task.text}</li>
           ))}
         </ul>
       );
     }
   }

   ReactDOM.render(<TodoWholistic />, document.getElementById("root"));
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
   <div id="root"></div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your TodoList class. `task.text` should be `task.tasks`

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
          <li key={task.id}>{task.tasks}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```